# Как считывать данные из txt файла на эмуляторе android?

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте! Уже весь мозг поломал, не могу разобраться с чтением данных из файла txt, почему-то, когда запускаешь сделанную программу, данные из файла txt отображаются на эмуляторе  с искажением русских букв, кодировка всех данных и программы стоит UTF-8 .

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобным? Как это лечится?

Comment: Вы пишете для андроида? Или о каком эмуляторе идет речь?

Comment: Да для андроида, эмулятор samsung galaxy s 4.4.4 api 19 через genymotion

Answer (score 1):

Чудес не бывает. Это просто означает, что кодировка русских символов в исходном файле не UTF-8, а скорее всего Win-1251.

Есть 2 варианта решения:

1. **Правильный** перекодировать исходный файл в UTF-8
2. **Кривой** на ходу перекодировать Win-1251 в UTF-8

P.S. В вашем тексте написано:

> Шаг 1. Отпускаем негатив (прощайте, страх, обида, жалость, стыд, злость... - на себя, на других, на жизнь, на весь белый свет...)

Comment: Спасибо, попробую сегодня, отпишусь вечером

Comment: нет, не получается, видимо, в mac дело, уже все варианты перепробовал,
Ладно, буду что-нибудь придумывать.
Спасибо за советы.

Comment: >видимо, в mac дело    

в чем дело? Поясните подробней

Comment: В маке кодировка своя. Почитайте [эту статью на хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/152737/)

Answer (score 0):

Если используете в качесве IDE Android Studio, то в gradle файле в самом конце пропишите

```
tasks.withType(org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile){
    options.encoding = "UTF-8"
}
```

Comment: Я новичок в android, использую eclipse, где там можно сделать правки?

Comment: тогда срочно переходите на Android Studio и забудьте про эклипс

Comment: хотелось бы с этим разобраться, столько времени с eclipse разбирался, а теперь на studio переходить, может, есть какой выход все же

Comment: А как файл читаете? Покажите кусок кода. 
И как выводите данные и куда?

Comment: п»ї<p>РЁР°Рі 1. РћС‚РїСѓСЃРєР°РµРј РЅРµРіР°С‚РёРІ
(РїСЂРѕС‰Р°РёМ†С‚Рµ, СЃС‚СЂР°С…, РѕР±РёРґР°, Р¶Р°Р»РѕСЃС‚СЊ, СЃС‚С‹Рґ, Р·Р»РѕСЃС‚СЊ... - РЅР° СЃРµР±СЏ, РЅР° РґСЂСѓРіРёС…, РЅР° Р¶РёР·РЅСЊ, РЅР° РІРµСЃСЊ Р±РµР»С‹РёМ† СЃРІРµС‚...)

вот так читает кусок кода, данные вывожу из txt файла на эмулятор  samsung galaxy s 4.4.4 api 19 через genymotion с помощью кода

Comment: 
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
  String itemname = "n" + bundle.getString("defStrID"); 
  
  Context context = getBaseContext(); 
  String text = readRawTextFile(context, getResources().getIdentifier(itemname, "raw", "com.example.project1"));
  
        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        String summary = "<html><body>" + text + "</body></html>";
        myWebView.loadData(summary, "text/html", "utf-8"); 
    }

Comment: Меня смущает вот это "String text = readRawTextFile(context, getResources().getIdentifier(itemname, "raw", "com.example.project1"));"

Попробуйте прочитать файл потоком:

FileInputStream fis;
final StringBuffer storedString = new StringBuffer();

try {
    fis = openFileInput("out.txt");
    DataInputStream dataIO = new DataInputStream(fis);
    String strLine = null;

    if ((strLine = dataIO.readLine()) != null) {
        storedString.append(strLine);
    }

    dataIO.close();
    fis.close();
}
catch  (Exception e) {  
}

Comment: Если поменя while на if, то будет читать по одной строке, с while читать весь файл построчно.

А вообще посмотрите вот тут http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12421814/how-can-i-read-a-text-file-in-android

в самом низу там есть вот такой код:

    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in,"UTF-8"));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1)

Тут, как видите, вы явно задаете кодировку файла.